# EXCEL: Check for Multiple Values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to check for multiple values using the FILTER function. Here is my code:

```
=FILTER(Projects!$A$2:$P$51,Projects!$E$2:$E$51="Completed")
```

I would like to check for additional values besides *Completed*. Like, *Canceled*, or *Review*.

Additionally, if I could check for a portion of case-insensitive text like, "rev" that could help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ISNUMBER(MATCH(...))`

```
=FILTER(Projects!$A$2:$P$51,ISNUMBER(MATCH("*"&Projects!$E$2:$E$51&"*",{"Completed","Canceled","Review"},0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

FILTER used to return multiple criteria

In this case, we're using the multiplication operator (*) to return all values in our array range (A5:D20) that have Apples AND are in the East region:

```
=FILTER(A5:D20,(C5:C20=H1)*(A5:A20=H2),"")
```

Also you can have a detail look at the given link

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759

Please see the image if you do not understand

[image]

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759

Comment: is this a chatGPT response?